# SQL Where Column1 = Column1 will only return non-nulls

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, where-clause

I'm working on a bigger problem, but have narrowed it down to this, in order to make this question easier to ask.

The following query:

```
Select * from User where Country = Country
```

Will only return the rows where Country is not null.  I would expect if Column1 is null it would return it because NULL = NULL.

Any input on why this is not working as I expect?

EDIT:

I am trying to do this:

```
Select * from User where Country = coalesce(@Country, Country)
```

If my variable @Country is null, I want it to pull everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL uses [three valued logic](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-and-the-snare-of-three-valued-logic/) (`true`, `false`, `unknown`) and comparisons to `NULL` (except for testing with the `IS [NOT] NULL` operator) evaluate as `unknown` not `true` as long as the session option [`ANSI_NULLS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx) is on.

For a row to be returned from your query the `WHERE` clause needs to evaluate to `true`.

Following your edit you can use

```
Select * 
from User 
where @Country is null or Country = @Country
option (recompile)
```

To return all rows when `@country is null`. Although probably better just to break these up into 2 cases to avoid the recompile penalty.

```
IF @Country is null
Select * 
from User 
ELSE
Select * 
from User 
Where Country = @Country
```

Answer (score 1):

NULL is never equal to NULL, so when Country is NULL, Country != Country

You test NULL's using the IS operator.

If you really want NULLS (and I dont really understand why you;d want such a query in the first place), then try..

`select * from User where IFNULL(Country, '') = IFNULL(Country, '')`

or

`select * from User where Country = Country or Country IS NULL`

Comment: Correct, NULL is not equal to NULL because both are undefined so one can't assess the equality of the two.

Comment: "NULL is never equal to NULL" -- not true. Hint: `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @onedaywhen: you are confusing `distinct` (defined in `SQL:2003 3.1.6.8`) and `equal` (defined in `SQL:2003 3.1.6.13`). These are different concepts in `SQL`, and `GROUP BY` groups `not distinct` values.